# Como criar um Controller para o ApplicationUser

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

Boa Tarde,
Estou tentando criar uma area de administrador para administrar as contas do banco de dados, mas estou tendo dificuldades, tenho a classe ApplicationUser e a classe LoginViewModel:

```
public class LoginViewModel 
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Usuario")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirmar Email")]
    [Compare("Email", ErrorMessage = "O email e a confimação de email não são iguais.")]
    public string ConfirmEmail { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirmar senha")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "A senha e a confimação de senha não são iguais.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Primeiro nome")]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public string PrimeiroNome { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Ultimo nome")]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public string UltimoNome { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Numero para contato")]
    [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
    public  string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Data de Nascimento")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public string DataNascimento { get; set; }
    public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Lembrar senha?")]
    public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string PrimeiroNome { get; set; }
    public string UltimoNome { get; set; }
    public string DataNascimento { get; set; }
}
```

queria criar uma tela mais ou menos assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que eu faco, estou perdido.

Comment: Mas quais são as dificuldades que você está tendo?

Comment: Eu preciso criar um conttroler do LoginViewModel para aparecer as informacoes?

Answer (score 0):

Eu separaria essa classe AplicationUser da classe LoginViewModel. 
Criaria arquivos separados e, a após isso adiciona um controlador AplicationUserController e utilize essa LoginViewModel para passar os valores nos parâmetros. Eu colocaria também as propriedades PrimeiroNome, UltimoNome e Data dentro da classe LoginViewModel. Separar as respnsabilidades.

```
EX:

public class LoginViewModel 
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Usuario")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirmar Email")]
    [Compare("Email", ErrorMessage = "O email e a confimação de email não são iguais.")]
    public string ConfirmEmail { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirmar senha")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "A senha e a confimação de senha não são iguais.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Primeiro nome")]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public string PrimeiroNome { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Ultimo nome")]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public string UltimoNome { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Numero para contato")]
    [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
    public  string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Data de Nascimento")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public string DataNascimento { get; set; }
    public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Lembrar senha?")]
    public bool RememberMe { get; set; }

    public string PrimeiroNome { get; set; }
    public string UltimoNome { get; set; }
    public string DataNascimento { get; set; }
}



public class ApplicationUserController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Create(LoginViewModel model)
    {
       return View();
    }
}
```